# Temperature sensor recommendation

Tags: pic, sensor, temperature, reflow

I am builing a homemade reflow oven, but I cant find a good and cheap temperature sensor that can survive the temperatures necessary for reflow (~250ºC or 482ºF).
Does anyone have a recommendation? 
I will be reading the output in a PIC ADC to control a relay.

Comment: Try https://www.adafruit.com/products/270. Sensor + insulation are good up to 900 ºF

Comment: my standard answer for this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/17692/411

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my home-brew reflow oven I used a PT-1K (1K Ohm at 0C) sensor. Much easier to interface than a thermocouple. I preferred it over the more common PT-100 type (100 Ohm at 0C) because the resistor values can be higher, which avoids self-heating, and makes wiring resistance less of a problem.

Comment: Could you send me the link where I might buy it?

Comment: I bought it from www.reichelt.de, PCA 1.2010 10. It is called a Platinum-chip temperature sensor.

Answer (score 4):

Thermocouples (such as type K) are good, cheap and (depending how their wires are insulated) easily cover more than the range of interest. They do need a stage of amplification before the ADC, however. Suppliers and circuit examples should be easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

And probably you'll never find a silicon-based plastic-packaged pcb mounted sensor, if it's this what you're looking for. For the basic reason those temperatures are extreme for electronic components

Have you heard about thermocouples? Maybe the oldest electronic temp sensor... still widespread in industrial environments. Take for example a type J. They go up to 750 C. Not enough?

Comment: I know the sensors, I just wanted recommendations from people who use it, so I might buy a good recommendend one and not get in trouble

Answer (score 0):

RTD would the best solution for the range of (<500 c).

source:

A. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer

B. http://www.omega.com/temperature/z/thertd.html

A decent Reference

Comment: Add a reference please

Comment: Kindly follow the references givena bove if still stuck raise a comment

Comment: Thank you for the references. Could you please update the Omega link? It appears to be broken

Comment: Kindly navigate to PT100(Platinum 100) on the below given site: http://www.omega.com/temperature/